# Satisfy TS-Compiler when checking variable in function

Tags: typescript

Given is the following exemplary class:

```
export class Inference {
  private counter?: number;

  initializeCounter() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }

  addNumberToCounter(boost: number) {
    if(typeof this.counter === "number") {
      this.counter += boost;
    }
  }
}
```

With the selection `if(typeof this.counter === "number")` I can safely add the `boost` parameter to `this.counter`. The TS-Compiler knows about the type of `this.counter` to be `number`.

If I extract the selection condition info a function, the TS-Compiler can no longer validate `this.counter` to be set.

```
  addNumberToCounter(boost: number) {
    if(this.isCounterSet()) {
      this.counter += boost;
    }
  }

  private isCounterSet() {
    return typeof this.counter === "number";
  }
```

Is there a way to satisfy TS-Compiler, if the selection result comes from a separate function?

Answer (score 1):

You could change `isCounterSet()` to be a [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). This can be done as follows:

```
addNumberToCounter(boost: number) {
  if(this.isCounterSet(this.counter)) {
    this.counter += boost;
  }
}

private isCounterSet(counter?: number): counter is number {
  return typeof this.counter === "number";
}
```

This requires you to change `isCounterSet` so that you pass in the value of `this.counter` as a parameter. What you are asking for is not possible any other way.

Comment: Thank you, for your reply. I know about this option, and this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: @scipper The answer to your question is still in my answer: "What you are asking for is not possible any other way".